# jdbc derby Syntax Error when create table

Tags: java, sql, derby

Please have a look:

```
CREATE TABLE Uzytkownik(
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    login VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Wizytowka(
    wizytowka_id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    tytul VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    tresc VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    premium_w INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
    id_user INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT wizytowka_id PRIMARY KEY (wizytowka_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES Uzytkownik(user_id)
);
```

I got Syntax Error: Encountered "(" at line 5, column 26.
Line 8, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your second create statement. Derby does not support a length attribute for the `integer` type. Therefore

```
premium_w INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
```

results in an error. Modify it to

```
premium_w INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

and it will work.

Comment: LOLS I add this and forgot to delete when checking sth else. thanks anyway :)